# Does Pivot Columns of the Column Space inform that Other Columns (dimensions) are Useless?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

This question is quite bothering me so I want to correct myself:

What I think of the column space as the span of individual dimention, so in the following X1 and X2 are Individual dimensions as follows:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 5\\
6 & 5 & 3\\
3 & 4 & 2
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
X_1 \\
X_2 \\
X_3 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

So the question is if we perform RREF of some arbitrary matrix and get column 1 and column 2 as the pivots. 
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$
Does it mean that $X_3$ useless because it is not the basis as well as the third column is useless?

Comment: You made up a random matrix here? Its reduced echelon form is the identity.

Comment: What if the RREF had instead been $\small{\pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&1&1\\0&0&0}}$?

Comment: @amd isnt this singularity? We have two parallel dimension.

Comment: Yes, and? The RREF in your question is also singular. There’s some direction that “collapses.” In your example, it’s in the direction of the $x_3$ axis; in the one above, it’s in the direction of $(0,1,-1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had made up a valid question, however, the answer is that if you can write $\vec b$ as a linear combination of the columns of $A$, i.e., you can solve $A\vec x=\vec b$, then — yes — you could write $\vec b$ as a linear combination of just the pivot columns. That is, we can rewrite the non-pivot columns as linear combinations of the pivot columns and therefore express $\vec b$ as a linear combination of just the pivot columns. This means that there will be a solution $X$ with each of the *free* (non-pivot) variables equal to $0$.

Geometrically, if you have a $2$-dimensional column space (as is the case with your RREF), then for any $\vec b$ in that column space, we get a *line* of solutions. What I said earlier is that this line must intersect the plane $x_3=0$. The line of solutions is parallel to the nullspace of the matrix. This nullspace cannot be contained in the plane $x_3=0$ unless one of the pivots is in the third column. (By the way, your RREF should in general have nonzero entries in the first two positions of the third column. Better to work with the general case here.)

Comment: I am bit lost at `The line of solutions is parallel to the nullspace of the matrix. This nullspace cannot be contained in the plane 3=0 unless one of the pivots is in the third column`

Comment: The solutions of $A\vec x=\vec b$ consists of the nullspace of $A$ (solutions of $A\vec x = \vec 0$) translated by a particular solution. For the nullspace to be parallel to the $x_1x_2$-plane, it must consist of vectors with $x_3=0$. In order to get vectors in the nullspace to have $x_3=0$ you must have a row $[0,0,1]$ in the echelon form.

Comment: allright. I shall review it further.